# variable value issue with python and threading (module)

Tags: python

Can someone tell me if I have multiple threads that change a global variable simultaneously ( for example:

```
Thread1: x+=1

Thread2: x-=1
```

)
what happens with the variable? Does one action wait until the other one is done? And if it doesn't how could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results?

Comment: I haven't tried it since I think it's hard to make it completly simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have something that's called a race condition.

A race condition occurs when two threads try to access a shared variable simultaneously.

The first thread reads the value from the shared variable. The second thread also reads the value from the same shared variable.

Then both threads try to change the value of the shared variable. And they race to see which thread writes a value to the variable last.

The value from the thread that writes to the shared variable last is preserved because it overwrites the value that the previous thread wrote.

To prevent race conditions, you can use the `Lock` class from the `threading` module.

Once a thread acquires a lock it will not release it until it will completes the changes to the shared variable.

Example:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from time import sleep
    
    
counter = 0
    
    
def increase(by, lock):
    global counter

    lock.acquire()

    local_counter = counter
    local_counter += by

    sleep(0.1)

    counter = local_counter
    print(f'counter={counter}')

    lock.release()


lock = Lock()

# create threads
t1 = Thread(target=increase, args=(10, lock))
t2 = Thread(target=increase, args=(20, lock))

# start the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()


# wait for the threads to complete
t1.join()
t2.join()


print(f'The final counter is {counter}')
```

Output:

```
counter=10
counter=30
The final counter is 30
```

As you can see the final counter is exactly 30 and the variable was not corrupted.